# Prefetched rows don't fill the table correctly

Tags: model, qooxdoo

I use qooxdoo 3.5, but same situation I got on 3.0.1.

Remote table is build according to [the example from docs](http://manual.qooxdoo.org/current/pages/widget/table_remote_model.html).

In represetatnion class I don't use antyhing fancy. The issue is that when data rows are exceeding the *BlockSize*, empty rows are generated. After using *reloadData* everything is filled properly. The problem is that using *reloadData* is not efficient. Did you meet similar problem with prefetching and cache data?

[**Link to screenshots**](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/nal9m4ogv4luznf/PGlj2Ls6Jb)

Remote table model:

```
qx.Class.define("atms.RemoteTableCases",
{
extend : qx.ui.table.model.Remote,

include: [qx.locale.MTranslation],

properties :
{
    test: {
        init:  '',
        nullable: true,
        event: "changeTest"
    },

    param :
    {
        init  : "?query=",
        check : "String"
    }
},

construct : function()
{
    this.base(arguments);
    var colnames = {            
        "status"       : this.tr("Status"),
        "user"         : this.tr("Assigned to"),
        "name"         : this.tr("Case Name"),
        "expected_time": this.tr("Expected time"),
        "result_time"  : this.tr("Result time"),
        "weight"       : this.tr("Impact factor")
    };
    var col_keys = new Array();
    var col_values = new Array();

    for (var key in colnames) {
        col_keys.push(key);
        col_values.push(colnames[key]);
    }
    this.base(arguments);
    this.setColumns(col_values, col_keys);
    this.__colKeys = col_keys;

    this.setColumnSortable(0, true);

    this.setBlockSize(4);
    this.__setupResources();
},

members :
{
    __colKeys: null,

    __setupResources: function() {
        this.__rows = new qx.io.rest.Resource({
            "get"      :   { method: "GET",    url: SERVER + "get_cases_count.json/{id}" },
            "getCases" :   { method: "GET",    url: SERVER + "get_cases.json/{test}{param}" }
        });
        this.__rows.addListener('getSuccess', function(e) {
            this._onRowCountCompleted(e.getData().content);
        }, this);
        this.__rows.addListener('getCasesSuccess', function(e) {
            this._onLoadRowDataCompleted(e.getData().content);
        }, this);
    },

    _loadRowCount : function() { this.__rows.get({id:this.getTest()}); },

    _onRowCountCompleted : function(result)
    {
        if (result != null) {
            this._onRowCountLoaded(result);
        }
    },

    _loadRowData : function(firstRow, lastRow) {
        var parameters = "?from=" + firstRow + "&to=" + lastRow;

        var sortIndex = this.getSortColumnIndex() == -1 ?
            'null' : this.__colKeys[this.getSortColumnIndex()];
        var sortOrder =  this.isSortAscending() ? "asc" : "desc";
        parameters += "&sortOrder=" + sortOrder + "&sortIndex=" + sortIndex;

        this.__rows.getCases({
            test:  this.getTest(),
            param: parameters
        });
    },

    _onLoadRowDataCompleted : function(result)
    {
        if (result != null) {
            this._onRowDataLoaded(result);
        }
    }
}
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please make sure, the data loaded in the method call _*onRowDataLoaded* corresponds exactly the data range requested by _*loadRowData : function(**firstRow**, **lastRow**)*.

Comment: Old question, but I decided to give feedback. As a backend I used web2py framework. There was a mistake in a controler (json api). In db query  limitby should be defined as (firstRow, lastRow+1)